# Finding the number of functions that map two specific elements

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Let's say I have two different sets, set $A$ and set $B$, where $|A|$ $\geq$ $|B|$. I am having a problem where one of my exercises is asking me, to sum up the question without totally just asking for answers on my exercises, find the number of functions that $\textbf{DON'T}$ map two specific elements between the sets. We are going from $A$ to $B$.

Where I am at right now, is that I think we are supposed to subtract the number of functions that do map the two elements from $|A|^{|B|}$, or am I just totally wrong with saying that? I am just confused on how do I find that number of functions I guess?

Comment: By functions that don't map two specific elements do you mean that you are given $a \in A, b\in B$ and you want the number of functions where $f(a) \neq b?$  Note that the number of unrestricted functions from $A$ to $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for clarifying my error in you last point.

Yes, you are correct in what you said as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider all functions from $A$ to $B$ and subtract the number that satisfy $f(a)=b$, yielding $$|B|^{|A|}-|B|^{|A\setminus \{a\}|}=|B|^{|A|}-|B|^{|A|-1}=|B|^{|A|-1}(|B|-1).$$  The last expression is the product suggested by @RossMillikan.

Comment: Is $|B|^{|A|-1}$ the one that satisfies $f(a) = b$?

Comment: Yes, once you have fixed $f(a)=b$, you need to map the remaining elements $A \setminus \{a\}$ to $B$.

Comment: So essentially, sorry if I am being redundant, you just removed an element from a set and found the $\textit{new}$ total number of functions?

Comment: Yes, for the "bad" functions $f$, the choice of where $f$ maps $a$ has already been decided ($f(a)=b$), so now you need to decide the values of $f$ for all other members of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You can think of it as the number of functions from the rest of $A$ to $B$ times the number of choices for $f(a)$.

Comment: From the rest of $A$ to $B$?? I am a bit confused by that.

Comment: From $A$ except $a$ to $B$.  We can split the definition of a function $f$ into a part that says what happens to $A\setminus \{a\}$ and a part that defines $f(a)$

Comment: So basically, we are trying to find the number of onto functions that exclude ${(y,3)}$

Comment: They don't have to be onto-that wasn't required anywhere and is not assumed in the $|B|^{|A|}$ value.